# Nested query in Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have three tables. I have to retrieve the data using Linq statement. My three table names are A,B,C. I connected join for connecting two tables A and B based on the id's like:

```
select ol, fN, LN, ci, co
from member
join details
on member_id = details_id
where details_id in
(select contacts_id from contacts where
contacts_id1 = 1 and contacts_usr_id = 1)
```

I am able to write the query up to the `where` condition, how can I write the query for the inner while condition?

Comment: can You post your table structure with real names?

Comment: Have you tried something ? By the way, the second part `where usr_id in (select contacts_id from table3 where usr_id = 1 and contacts_id = 1)` is... rather strange.

Comment: Thanx for the reply,In that portion only I am also facing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
      var idlist = (from tbl in table3
                    where tbl.usr_id == 1 && tbl.contacts_id == 1
                    select tbl.contacts_id ).ToList();

     var x = from A in table1
              from B in table2 where A.user_id == B.user_id                
              && idlist.Contains(A.user_id)
              select new { a = A.a, b = A.b, c = A.c, d = B.d, e = B.e };
```

check and let me know if that work.

Comment: Thanx for the reply,It is showing error at the where idlist.contains(new {contacts_id = A.user_id}) and it is displaying "Does not contain definition for 'Contains' and best Extension method over loaded System.Linq.IEnumerable"

Comment: maybe you are missing some library references like System.Data.Linq or System.Linq.

Comment: i have included those library functions

Comment: Displaying like:system.Linq.Iquerable does not contain the defnition for Contains

Comment: Displaying Error at this line,from A in table1 join B in table2 on A.user_id equals B.user_id

Comment: "Only assignment,call,increment,decrement can be used as a statement" and complete portion after From A is showing error.I think we closed the braces before ToList(),So the remaining portion it is not considering as query

Comment: please check your code more accurately.i got same code in my class but not giving any error.

Comment: i have edited code for last time and i am sure it is errorless.please check.

Comment: Sorry,again it is showing error at the join B and where places.

Comment: hi,sorry for late reply,There is no error in the query but when i pass this value to the view,it is throwing the error.

Comment: dont know.I am checking for that

Answer (score 0):

Try flipping the query upside down. How about the following:

```
var query = 
   from t3 in table3
   where t3.user_id = 1 && t3.contacts_id = 1
   join t2 in table2 on t3.contacts_id equals t2.usr_id
   join t1 in table1 on t2.usr_id equals t1.userid
   select new {t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t1.d, t1.e};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,It is working fine,can we do it using Lambda expressions

Comment: @nanicharan - Why do you need to do it using Lambda Expressions? LINQ is just syntactical sugar anyway.

Comment: You can do it with lambda expressions. I find the join syntax to be more readable/maintainable using query comprehensions, but to each their own. You can use LINQPad to translate a working query into the Lambda syntax if you can't do it yourself otherwise.

Comment: sorry for this,actually query is working but it is not giving the output for my sql query